# Raspberry Pi MCP3008 ADC converter always returns same value for sensor

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, adc

I have a moisture sensor and it uses analog so I purchased MCP3008 ADC. I have installed all the packages, ensured the SPI is enabled, checked multiple MCP3008 chips, ran 2 separate python scripts for this, used multiple sensors and made sure they work by simply letting it read digital signal as I place it in water and it changes from 1 to 0, i quadruple checked all my plug-ins, and checked every channel in the MCP chip, and used meter to ensure continuity. So, I have done pretty much everything I can think of and I am getting the same max value no matter what. I can't figure out what is wrong. Is there anything I can try that I haven't?

To conclude, the problem is that I always get the same value in my output regardless of channel, sensor, chip, or py script used. Here is one example script.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import busio
import digitalio
import board
import adafruit_mcp3xxx.mcp3008 as MCP
from adafruit_mcp3xxx.analog_in import AnalogIn

# create the spi bus
spi = busio.SPI(clock=board.SCK, MISO=board.MISO, MOSI=board.MOSI)

# create the cs (chip select)
cs = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D22)

# create the mcp object
mcp = MCP.MCP3008(spi, cs)
print(mcp)

# create an analog input channel on pin 0
chan0 = AnalogIn(mcp, MCP.P1)

print('Raw ADC Value: ', chan0.value)
print('ADC Voltage: ' + str(chan0.voltage) + 'V')
```

this always prints...
Raw ADC Value:  65472
ADC Voltage: 3.2968276493476765V

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! At first sight your code looks reasonable. The problem you are experiencing might go beyond the code you posted. I would suggest to move this question to [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) where it might get more attention from experts that might be familiar with the hardware and libraries you are using.

Comment: How do I move it?

Comment: Just delete it here and open a new question there.

Comment: I'll leave it open here and post a link to this one if that is OK.